# Cloud formation error with cft created from cloud former

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have created below CFT from cloud former and i am very new to CFT but i am getting below error

```
 [/Resources/Description] resource definition is malformed
```

I have tried and changed CFT but to no avail

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Resources": {
        "xomevaluationprodvpc": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
            "Properties": {
                "CidrBlock": "10.213.128.0/17",
                "InstanceTenancy": "default",
                "EnableDnsSupport": "true",
                "EnableDnsHostnames": "true",
                "Tags": [{
                        "Key": "account",
                        "Value": "xome-valuation"
                    },
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "xome-valuation-prod-vpc"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "xomevaluationprodpublicsubnet": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
            "Properties": {
                "CidrBlock": "10.213.128.0/23",
                "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2a",
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "xome-valuation-prod-vpc"
                },
                "Tags": [{
                        "Key": "account",
                        "Value": "xome-valuation-prod"
                    },
                    {
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "production-public"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "xomevaluationprodprivatesubnet": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
            "Properties": {
                "CidrBlock": "10.213.134.0/23",
                "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2a",
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "xome-valuation-prod-vpc"
                },
                "Tags": [{
                        "Key": "Name",
                        "Value": "production-private-"
                    },
                    {
                        "Key": "account",
                        "Value": "xome-valuation-prod"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Description": "VPC Creation",
        "Outputs": {
            "xomevaluationprod-vpcId": {
                "Value": {
                    "Ref": "xomevaluationprodvpc"
                }
            },
            "xomevaluationprodpublic-subnetId": {
                "Value": {
                    "Ref": "xomevaluationprodpublicsubnet"
                }
            },
            "xomevaluationprodprivate-subnetId": {
                "Value": {
                    "Ref": "xomevaluationprodprivatesubnet"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What changes should i make to CFT to make it work.

CloudFormer is a template creation beta tool that creates an AWS CloudFormation template from existing AWS resources in your account. You select any supported AWS resources that are running in your account, and CloudFormer creates a template in an Amazon S3 bucket.

Use CloudFormer to produce templates that you can use as a starting point. Not all AWS resources or resource properties are supported.

Important

CloudFormer is currently in beta. We recommend against utilizing it in critical or production environments.

The following list outlines the basic procedure for using CloudFormer:

Provision and configure the required resources using your existing processes and tools.

Create and launch a CloudFormer stack.

CloudFormer is an AWS CloudFormation stack. You run CloudFormer by launching the stack from your AWS environment. It runs on a t2.medium Amazon EC2 instance and requires no other resources.

Use CloudFormer to create a template using your existing AWS resources and save the template to an Amazon S3 bucket.

Delete the CloudFormer stack.

You usually don't need CloudFormer beyond this point, so you can avoid additional charges by deleting the stack.

Use the template to launch a new stack, as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have added `Description` and `Outputs` within `Resources` section. They should be defined outside `Resources`. Below is the fixed json of your CFT.

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "xomevaluationprodvpc": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.213.128.0/17",
        "InstanceTenancy": "default",
        "EnableDnsSupport": "true",
        "EnableDnsHostnames": "true",
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "account",
            "Value": "xome-valuation"
          },
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "xome-valuation-prod-vpc"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "xomevaluationprodpublicsubnet": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.213.128.0/23",
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2a",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "xome-valuation-prod-vpc"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "account",
            "Value": "xome-valuation-prod"
          },
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "production-public"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "xomevaluationprodprivatesubnet": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.213.134.0/23",
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2a",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "xome-valuation-prod-vpc"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "production-private-"
          },
          {
            "Key": "account",
            "Value": "xome-valuation-prod"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Description": "VPC Creation",
  "Outputs": {
    "xomevaluationprod-vpcId": {
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "xomevaluationprodvpc"
      }
    },
    "xomevaluationprodpublic-subnetId": {
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "xomevaluationprodpublicsubnet"
      }
    },
    "xomevaluationprodprivate-subnetId": {
      "Value": {
        "Ref": "xomevaluationprodprivatesubnet"
      }
    }
  }
}
```